# How to add generic event handler at runtime to collection of generic objects with different generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, event-handling

I have some generic class GeneralClass which contains event with generic event handler

```
GeneralClass<T>
{
    public event DataChangedHandler<T> DataChanged;
}
```

And I can write next code:

```
class MainClass
{
    public void OnDataChanged<T>(T parametrs)
    {
    }

    var MyClass1 = new GenericClass<classA>();
    var MyClass2 = new GenericClass<classB>();

    MyClass1.DataChanged+= OnDataChanged;
    MyClass2.DataChanged+= OnDataChanged;
}
```

Everything works as I expected. But is it possible to store all different instance of my generic class in one collection and add event handler in cycle? Something like this:

```
class MainClass{
    public void OnDataChanged<T>(T parametrs)
    {
    }

    var MyClass1= new GenericClass<classA>();
    var MyClass2= new GenericClass<classB>();

    List<> genericClasses = new List<>();
    genericClasses.Add(MyClass1);
    genericClasses.Add(MyClass1);
    genericClasses.foreach(t=>t.DataChanged+=OnDataChanged)
}
```

I know I can store all my instance in List of object but then I don’t have access to event. If I cast object to GenericClass I must specify generic parameter(type ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would seriously, seriously ask you to reconsider your approach - having a collection of different generic classes, especially when you don't know which is which is a first step on a road to disaster.

Having said that - it is technically doable, like this:

```
var dynamicList = new List<dynamic> { MyClass1, MyClass2 };
foreach (var generalClass in dynamicList)
{
    this.AddEventHandler(generalClass);
}
```

with the following 'helper' method:

```
public void AddEventHandler<T>(GeneralClass<T> item)
{
    item.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I agree with you to some extent. With 'dynamic' I lose type safety. But when I look at my code and see:

Comment: MyClass1.DataChanged+=OnDataChanged; MyClass2.DataChanged+=OnDataChanged;                                             . .................................................... MyClass12.DataChanged+=OnDataChanged;                                      This seriously annoys me. And I can't change generic classes, because i don't have access to them. I tried to make interface or use inheritance. But it didn't help.